# How to update multiple table column with multiple condition in PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a single optimized query to update multiple columns based on different conditions. I have written a query and it's working fine but I need a more optimized query to do so. 
Is there any other way to achieve the above goal?

Below is what I have written

```
UPDATE table1
      SET
      val1 = ( 
      CASE
            WHEN w_id = 287 THEN 'test1'
            WHEN w_id = 288 THEN 'test2'
            WHEN w_id = 469 THEN 'test3'
            WHEN w_id = 468 THEN 'test4'
            WHEN w_id IN (
                                        SELECT
                                            w_id
                                        FROM
                                            table1 t1
                                            INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.w_id 
            ) THEN 'test5'
        END ),
      val2 = ( 
      CASE
            WHEN w_id IN( 287, 288, 468, 469 ) THEN 'test6'
            WHEN w_id IN (
                                        SELECT
                                            w_id
                                        FROM
                                            table1 t1
                                            INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.w_id 
            ) THEN 'test6'
        END ),
              val3 = ( 
      CASE
            WHEN w_id IN( 287, 288, 468, 469 ) THEN 'test7'
            WHEN w_id IN (
                                        SELECT
                                            w_id
                                        FROM
                                            table1 t1
                                            INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.w_id
            ) THEN 'test7'
        END );
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, you do repeat the same subquery three times. I don't have experience with postgresql, but if you can change that subquery into a join I think you should see a big improvement on performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only optimization I can think of for now.

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT
    w_id
 FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.w_id 
)
UPDATE Table1  
      SET
      Val1 = (
      CASE
            WHEN w_id = 287 THEN 'test1'
            WHEN w_id = 288 THEN 'test2'
            WHEN w_id = 469 THEN 'test3'
            WHEN w_id = 468 THEN 'test4'
            WHEN w_id IN (SELECT W_id from CTE) THEN 'test5'
      END ),
      val2 = (
      CASE
            WHEN w_id IN( 287, 288, 468, 469 ) THEN 'test6'
            WHEN w_id IN (SELECT W_ID from CTE) THEN 'test6'
      END ),
      val3 = ( 
      CASE
            WHEN w_id IN( 287, 288, 468, 469 ) THEN 'test7'
            WHEN w_id IN (SELECT W_ID FROM CTE) THEN 'test7'
      END );
```